# Cannot duplicate my form with v-for vuejs help needed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am having a form  where user can put in the input the message he wants to deliver and the sec which stands for how many sec do you want to show it(timeout),
I made an add button which should put in the screen another one form where he can add something different text and sec ...

I put v-for to my form .My code looks like this:

```
<v-form ref="form" class="container" v-for="(input,i) in inputs" :key="i" lazy-validation>
  <v-container class="container">
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex lg12 class="container">
        <v-text-field v-model="inputs.text" label="Text" placeholder="" required></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>

      <v-flex lg3 class="container">
        <v-text-field v-model="inputs.sec" label="Millisec" required type="number"></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>

      <v-flex lg12 class="container">
        <v-btn color="black" @click="addLines(i)" v-show="i == inputs.length-1">ADD</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex lg6 class="container">
        <v-btn color="dark" @click="onSubmit">Submit</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-form>
```

data what i am having:

```
data() {
    return {
      inputs: [
        {
          text: "",
          sec: 0
        }
      ]
```

i decleared that addLines(i) method but  but im not sure how should i duplicate the form thats when i  need your help, i need the form to not be the same form so if i write to one form do not show it in the duplicate one.

```
addLines(i) {
      this.inputs.push({ text: "", sec: 0 });
    },
```

when i run this the program says

```
75:14  error  'i' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

button is not showing as well:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is es-lint error. To solve change this line like this (remove the unused `i`)

```js
addLines() {
  this.inputs.push({ text: "", sec: 0 });
}
```

and change your template to:

```html
<v-form
  ref="form"
  class="container"
  v-for="(input,i) in inputs"
  :key="i"
  lazy-validation
>
  <v-container class="container">
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex lg12 class="container">
        <v-text-field
          v-model="input.text"
          label="Text"
          placeholder=""
          required
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>

      <v-flex lg3 class="container">
        <v-text-field
          v-model="input.sec"
          label="Millisec"
          required
          type="number"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>

      <v-flex lg12 class="container">
        <v-btn color="black" @click="addLines(i)" v-show="i == inputs.length-1"
          >ADD</v-btn
        >
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex lg6 class="container">
        <v-btn color="dark" @click="onSubmit">Submit</v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-form>
```

Comment: Yes, thats write but when i am duplicating my form if i write to one form its automatically writing to the duplicated one , how can i prevent this? so  i can use  usefully the other one form ,  thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now I see what your real problem was, I thought just es-lint. I didn't tested it, let me know if it works or still some bug

Comment: hello thanks for your answer now the two forms are not the same , but now i am having a problem where i want to set the store to the message what was given to the input. So iam having a function onSubmit where i am having my mapActions,
i want to set myMessage state  so i used this.setMessage(this.inputs.text) but its not working now  dont you know by any chances how should i  do the mapactions thing, i should somehow get the this.inputs[i].text no? but i am not able to give to my onSubmit method an index, if its not clear please give me your discord where i can   show you more detailwise

Comment: Hi! 
Great. Please mark this question as solved and open a new question for the part where you need help. 

Make sure to include in your question the code you are using for the method: onSubmit